# DOM javascript duda de reputación de elementos

Tags: javascript, dompdf

Estaba haciendo unas cuestiones en JavaScript y utilizando DOM y la console me di cuenta de que los elementos obtenidos (`getElementById`) se pueden trabajar como arreglo.  Yo trabaja de la siguiente manera que fue como lo aprendí de un libro:

```
Var dom = document.getElementbyId("demo");
Dom.childNodes[];
```

Así accedía a los valores, pero si uso así funciona igual:

```
Var dom = document.getElementbyId("demo");
Dom[i];
```

Pero quiero saber cual es la diferencia entre `Dom.childNodes[i]` y `Dom[i]`. ¿Es uno mejor uno que el otro?

Answer (score 1):

Para el caso que dices puede que funcionen ambas de la misma manera ya que normalmente `getElementById()` devuelve un solo elemento.
 Pero en el caso que uses otra función como
 `x = doc.getElementByTagName("title")` cambia un poco porque si luego haces `x[0]` te retornará el primer elemento con etiqueta **title**, sin embargo si haces `x.childNodes[]` te retornará la lista de elementos hijos de `x`.

Comment: Eso lo se man, Pero o sea que diferencia hay en recorrer  los elementos así x.childnodes[i] que de esta forma x[i]?